# Gitlab api hangs when using wsl-2 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, curl, gitlab, wsl-2

In my company I have a gitlab available at https://gitlab.mycompany.com.

On my computer, running Windows 10, I'm trying to use the Gitlab api using curl.

In a dos terminal, it's working fine.

```
>curl -v https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/groups
*   Trying 10.57.36.28...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to gitlab.mycompany.com (10.57.36.28) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with gitlab.mycompany.com port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 188 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 188 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with gitlab.mycompany.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with gitlab.mycompany.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 2097
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 2097 length 4096
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 93 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with gitlab.mycompany.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 274
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 274 length 4096
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with gitlab.mycompany.com port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> GET /api/v4/groups HTTP/1.1
> Host: gitlab.mycompany.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
...
```

Now I'm trying the same within a wsl2 ubuntu 20.04 terminal

```
>curl -v https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/groups
*   Trying 10.57.36.28:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to gitlab.mycompany.com (10.57.36.28) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):

... hangs for 1 or 2 minutes ...

* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to gitlab.mycompany.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to gitlab.mycompany.com:443
```

I also tried to add `--insecure` option to be sure but same result.

I tried on a linux server and it is working.

In my wsl2 ubuntu terminal, I also tried with other https sites, internal and external, and it is working.

I don't understand what's the problem.  It seems the server is not responding to the client handshake.  But why ?